# Populating listview method not running

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to populate my `ListView` with an observable list but the code doesn't even seem to be running.

I have a Controller class which controls all the fooddrink items

```
package sample;

import com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FoodDrinkController {
    private ArrayList<FoodDrink> fullList = new ArrayList<>();

    //constructor with some stuff in it
    public FoodDrinkController(){
        FoodDrink cola = new FoodDrink("Coca Cola", 2.99, Global.itemtype.DRINK);
        FoodDrink pepsi = new FoodDrink("Pepsi", 2.99, Global.itemtype.DRINK);
        FoodDrink burger = new FoodDrink("burger", 7.99, Global.itemtype.MAIN);

        fullList.add(cola);
        fullList.add(pepsi);
        fullList.add(burger);
    }

    public ObservableList<FoodDrink> filterByType(Global.itemtype itemtype){
        ArrayList<FoodDrink> subList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (FoodDrink listItem : fullList){
            if(listItem.getItemtype().equals(itemtype)){
                subList.add(listItem);
            }
        }
        return FXCollections.observableArrayList(subList);
    }

    //plain old main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //SelectDrinkController fbtd = new SelectDrinkController();
        //System.out.println(fbtd.filterByType("DRINK"));

        FoodDrinkController fdc = new FoodDrinkController();
        System.out.println(fdc.filterByType(Global.itemtype.DRINK));
    }
}
```

and a controller for the gui

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableArray;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class SelectDrinkControllerGUI extends Application {

    private FoodDrinkController fdc = new FoodDrinkController();

    @FXML
    ListView lvDrinks = new ListView();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        ObservableList items = fdc.filterByType(Global.itemtype.DRINK);
        System.out.println(items);

        lvDrinks.getItems().addAll(items);
    }
}
```

So when I run the program it just shows an empty `ListView` instead of the DRINK items I put into the controller.

Comment: You seem to have reversed the roles of your two classes. The `FoodDrinkController` should be the FXML controller class and contain the `@FXML` fields and initialize method. Note that `#initialize(URL,ResourceBundel)` will only be invoked if the controller implements `javafx.fxml.Initializable`. And your `SelectDrinkControllerGUI` class should be the main class which loads the FXML and adds the result to the scene graph.

Comment: You may want to read a basic tutorial on JavaFX: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/index.html. Also see https://github.com/mhrimaz/AwesomeJavaFX#tutorials